# ExactTarget: is there a REST API to add subscribers to a list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, fuel-sdk, rest

I have successfully used the Python Fuel SDK to add subscribers to a list:
https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Python/blob/77d9d16b51952fcb90564ae456a65794b56e1554/FuelSDK/client.py#L217

I would like to use the REST API.  I only see documentation for a SOAP API (which is in fact used by FuelSDK.client.AddSubscriberToList()

No dice?

Comment: No update on this? It really sucks to have to use PHP for something like this vs NODE

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you are correct no dice.  Its in the works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Timothy.  Is there a timeline on the horizon?  Adding users does seem like core functionality.

Comment: Ummmm.... 2 years ago this was 'in the works'.  I can't find this functionality still.  Anyone know the status?

Comment: Anybody know if this was ever added to the REST API?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing like a directive to ensure that existing SOAP also get ported to REST.   It's going to be hit or miss.

Comment: when will this functionality be available with the rest API? seems like basic stuff since subscribers are a crucial part of the platform. Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score -1):

SOAP is so painful... FuelSDK doesn't work well with Maven (or at all in some cases like Adobe Experience Manager).  It would be great if some attention could be given to REST.